# C# Image loses color when saved

Tags: c#, image, printing, colors, save

I'm working in a little application that will send images to a card printer (Datacard brand), this program should convert the image to only two colors (just like black and white) RGB(217,217,217) and pure white. The problem is that even if in my screen the pictures looks converted, when I save/print the image, it looks black and white.

This method converts the image to black and white so I can later replace only the black color with the RGB 217,217,217

```
public static Bitmap BitmapTo1Bpp(Bitmap img)
{
        int w = img.Width;
        int h = img.Height;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h),ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        byte[] scan = new byte[(w + 7) / 8];
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            {
                if (x % 8 == 0) scan[x / 8] = 0;
                Color c = img.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (c.GetBrightness() >= 0.5) scan[x / 8] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
            }
            Marshal.Copy(scan, 0, (IntPtr)((long)data.Scan0 + data.Stride * y), scan.Length);
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);
        return bmp;
}
```

This method replaces the black color for the new one:

```
public static Image ImageToRGB217_2(Image image)
    {
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new[]
        {
            new float[] {0.851f, 0.851f, 0.851f, 1.000f, 0.000f},
            new float[] {0.851f, 0.851f, 0.851f, 1.000f, 0.000f},
            new float[] {0.851f, 0.851f, 0.851f, 1.000f, 0.000f},
            new float[] {0.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f},
            new float[] {1.000f, 1.000f, 1.000f, 0.000f, 0.000f}
        });

        Image img = ApplyColorMatrix(image, colorMatrix);
        return img;
    }

private static Bitmap ApplyColorMatrix(Image sourceImage, ColorMatrix colorMatrix)
    {
        Bitmap bmp32BppSource = GetArgbCopy(sourceImage);
        Bitmap bmp32BppDest = new Bitmap(bmp32BppSource.Width, bmp32BppSource.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        try
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp32BppDest))
            {
                ImageAttributes bmpAttributes = new ImageAttributes();
                bmpAttributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix);

                graphics.DrawImage(bmp32BppSource, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp32BppSource.Width, bmp32BppSource.Height),
                    0, 0, bmp32BppSource.Width, bmp32BppSource.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, bmpAttributes);

            }

            bmp32BppSource.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Ocurrió un error al intentar aplicar el filtro UV en una de las imágenes, error:" + ex.Message, "Convertidor", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return bmp32BppDest;
    }

private static Bitmap GetArgbCopy(Image sourceImage)
    {
        Bitmap bmpNew = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpNew))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(sourceImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height), new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            graphics.Flush();
        }

        return bmpNew;
    }
```

And here is where I call both:

```
private void usarFiltroRGB217ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = UVImage.ImageToRGB217_2(UVImage.BitmapTo1Bpp((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image));
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

This is how the result looks on screen: http://i127.photobucket.com/albums/p128/dawc159951/Preview_zpsxqtzht2a.jpg

But when I save/print, this is what i get:
http://i127.photobucket.com/albums/p128/dawc159951/217_zpsbmuobnrw.png

This is the saving method:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            Bitmap tmp = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            tmp.Save(path, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            if (File.Exists(path))
                Process.Start(path);
        }
```

I would appreciate any help to find out why i'm not able to get result i need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you've either uploaded the same image link twice, or they are identical.

Comment: == the links are identical not just the images

Comment: I'm sorry, it is fixed now.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine saving directly from a PB or converting back to a Bitmap.  Make sure you have the right reference and that whatever the default png image viewer is, it isnt to blame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for taking the time for checking my code, I made more tests with the same results, also i can't use png images, they have to be bmp, and they look black and white after saving/printing

Comment: If you have a 1bpp image, that's indexed. All you really need to do to change the colours is edit the palette; no need for the transformation matrix. As for the problem, I'm fairly sure that what you see on the first image is a picture in which the first colour is set to transparent and just showing the colour of the controls behind it.